# PostgreSQL - select aggregated column from joined table and use it to sum

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregation

I want to select fields that aggregated from three tables and output three fields for the post, `postId`, `calculatedRate` and `count`, i tried but not working

currently i have this sample query just get `count` and `postId`

```
select
    mr.count,
    mr.postId
from
    (
        select
            "m"."postId" as postId,
            count("m"."postId") as count
        from
            "Rating" r
        left join "Messenger" m on
            "r"."id" = "m"."ratingId"
        group by
            "m"."postId"
    ) mr
group by
    mr.postId,
    mr.count
```

Messenger (mapping table for Post and Rating)

| id | postId | ratingId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 6 |

Post

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | post one |
| 2 | post two |

Rating

| id | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5.0 | 5.0 |
| 5 | 3.0 | 3.0 |
| 6 | 2.0 | 4.0 |

Expected result (calculatedRate = average within same post id((rating.a + rating.b) / 2))

| id | postId | calculatedRate | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4.0 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3.0 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got what you're looking for, but if you want the `COUNT` and `CALCULATEDRATE` for each `MESSENGER.ID` then the following should do it

```
SELECT 
MESSENGER.ID,
POST.ID POSTID, 
COUNT(*) NR_RATINGS,
(RATING.A + RATING.B)/2 CALCULATEDRATE
FROM 
RATING JOIN MESSENGER ON RATING.ID = MESSENGER.RATINGID
JOIN POST ON MESSENGER.POSTID=POST.ID
```

**Edit**: if you want the average by post you can achieve that with the following

```
SELECT 
POST.ID POSTID, 
COUNT(*) NR_RATINGS,
avg((RATING.A + RATING.B)/2) CALCULATEDRATE
FROM 
RATING JOIN MESSENGER ON RATING.ID = MESSENGER.RATINGID
JOIN POST ON MESSENGER.POSTID=POST.ID
GROUP BY POST.ID
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, actually i want `count` and `calculatedRate` for each post

Comment: I edited the original post to add the aggregation